# how to resize or move all the child widgets of stack when one of it's grandchild is input TextField in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have positioned(using Align) two child widgets within stack widget and one of it contains form TextField to take input. When I clicked to enter data, only it's parent widget is moved up on Keypad entered as in the below picture.
Is there any way to move/resize the child widgets of stack while entering data from keypad.

Source code:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/playingboard2.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            child: null,
          ),
          _buildSelfPlayer(), // Returns the widget with form input and other widgets
          _buildBank(), // top center, shows two pictures of bank
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: did you try wrapping the `Stack` in a `SingleChildScrollView` with vertical scroll direction?

Comment: Yes, I tried, then all the widgets lost alignment and pileup at top center.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see another fix for this, while also making use of `Stack` widget.

So instead I'd suggest you to use `Column` widget wrapped inside a `SingleChildScrollView`. I tried it and it works as intended. The other children move up too along with the `TextField`, so maintaining the distance between them and not overlapping.

For the background image, you can wrap the `Scaffold` in a `Container`, use that image in the Column decoration and make the Scaffold's `backgroundColor` to `Colors.transparent`.